# IF statement within a SELECT - SQL

Tags: sql, select

I'm trying to write a query, that selects a number of values. I only want it to select one of the values if it isn't null.

I'm trying to use a case when but it is erroring.

```
SELECT pick_no, 
   pd.product, 
   from_warehouse, 
   to_warehouse, 
   qty_pick, 
   qty_check, 
   qty_picked, 
   qty_checked, 
   long_description, 
   ROUND(qty_pick / stk.pallet_unit_qty, 2) as [PalletQty], 
   ph.date_picking,
   stk.bin_no,
   CASE WHEN qty_picked <> null
            THEN ROUND(qty_picked / stk.pallet_unit_qty, 2) as [pltCheck]
            ELSE '0' END

FROM
```

Comment: try using NOT NULL?

Comment: should be `CASE WHEN qty_picked IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Or simply `coalesce(ROUND(qty_picked / stk.pallet_unit_qty, 2), 0) as [pltCheck]`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null is a tricky beast, you can't use equality operands on it. Also your else clause was returning a `CHAR` when the first clause returns a `FLOAT` :

```
CASE WHEN qty_picked IS NOT NULL
        THEN ROUND(qty_picked / stk.pallet_unit_qty, 2) as [pltCheck]
        ELSE 0 END
```

A simpler way to achieve your goal is to use `COALESCE` :

```
COALESCE(ROUND(qty_picked / stk.pallet_unit_qty, 2),0) as [pltCheck]
```